# Caesar Cipher with key in java

Tags: java

Im just working on this ceasar cipher encryption program in java. Where you ask the user to enter a text and key that would encrypt the text. 
                If they dont enter a number it will enter a random number. Not trying to decrypt the text just yet. 
                Also getting a error At line 29 the cmd keeps saying bad operand types for binary operator.

```
            import java.util.Scanner;
            import java.util.Random;
            public class A {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    System.out.println("This program encrypts text you enter using the Caesar Cipher.\n");
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String text;
                    String line;
                    String choice;
                    String shift;
                    char[] alphabet = {'A', 'B','C','D','E', 'F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
                    int key;
                    int caeserVal;
                    int sum;
                    String doAgain;

                    do {
                        System.out.println("Enter a line text to encrypt: ");
                        line = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter the key between -25 and 25. Enter 0 to have it generate a random key: ");
                        key = sc.nextInt();
                        sum = 0;
                        char[] plaintext = args[0].toCharArray();
                        shift = args[1];

                        for(int i = 0; i < plaintext.length; i++) {
                            for(int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
                                if(alphabet[j] == plaintext[i]) {
                                    plaintext[i] = alphabet[(j + shift) % alphabet.length];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                            String ciphertext = new String(plaintext);
                            System.out.println(ciphertext);
                            caeserVal = sum + key;
                        System.out.printf("The text encrypted with key %d is %s.\n", key,caeserVal);
                        System.out.print("Try again(y or n)? ");
                        choice = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                    }while(choice.equals("Y"));
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using this program.");



                }
            }
```

Comment: Which line is line 29?

Comment: plaintext[i] = alphabet[(j + shift) % alphabet.length];

Comment: `shift` is a String, and so you can't use it in an algebraic expression, and so the error message makes perfect sense. Fix that first.

Comment: Array index should be integers. Cast if it a number

Comment: why are you not using String variable 'line' as plaintext instead of args[0]? And where are you generating random number if user enters 0

Comment: Only been using java for a few weeks and I haven't done the random yet, just trying to get the regular words to encrypt first.

Answer (score 0):

If 2nd command line argument is integer

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
            import java.util.Random;
            public class A {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    System.out.println("This program encrypts text you enter using the Caesar Cipher.\n");
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String text;
                    String line;
                    String choice;
                    String shift;
                    char[] alphabet = {'A', 'B','C','D','E', 'F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
                    int key;
                    int caeserVal;
                    int sum;
                    String doAgain;

                    do {
                        System.out.println("Enter a line text to encrypt: ");
                        line = sc.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter the key between -25 and 25. Enter 0 to have it generate a random key: ");
                        key = sc.nextInt();
                        sum = 0;
                        char[] plaintext = args[0].toCharArray();
                        shift = args[1];

                        for(int i = 0; i < plaintext.length; i++) {
                            for(int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
                                if(alphabet[j] == plaintext[i]) {
                                    plaintext[i] = alphabet[((j + Integer.parseInt(shift)) % alphabet.length)];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                            String ciphertext = new String(plaintext);
                            System.out.println(ciphertext);
                            caeserVal = sum + key;
                        System.out.printf("The text encrypted with key %d is %s.\n", key,caeserVal);
                        System.out.print("Try again(y or n)? ");
                        choice = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                    }while(choice.equals("Y"));
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using this program.");



                }
            }
```

If it is not integer, then it would throw an error.

Comment: When I enter a key in the cmd this error pops up "Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at A.main(A.java:23)

Comment: That is because you need to pass 2 command line arguments as you are providing shift as args[1], which implies that it is 2nd argument

Comment: What do you mean by that, I'm having trouble trying to do that.

Comment: In main see the arguments String args[], this would take inputs through command line, so if you given one input then it would be considered as args[0] and so on. So in you code you have given it as args[1], so the second argument from command line is the value you are looking for..If you are still finding it difficult, then change this statement :  shift = args[1]; to shift = "1" (any number of your choice) or take input using Scanner.